# Assembly movsbq instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64, twos-complement, sign-extension

I understood the difference between `movz` and `movs`.
`movz` fills the empty bytes with zeros while `movs` fills them with sign bit (zeros or ones).

However, I came accross the following example

1. `movabsq $0x0011223344556677, %rax`
2. `movb $0xAA, %dl`
3. `movb %dl, %al`
4. `movsbq %dl, %rax`

After line 3, `%rax = 00112233445566AA`. I undertood untill this. But I could not get why %rax is equal to  `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFAA` after line 4. Shouldn't it be `00000000000000AA` because empty bits are filled with zero as %dl is positive ?

Comment: `%dl` is not positive. `0xAA` has the sign bit set. That will be used to fill the extended bits.

Comment: 0xAA, as a signed byte, is -86.  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAA is also -86.  As a signed byte, any hex value at or above 0x80 is negative.  Positive values for signed byte range from 0x00 to 0x7F, and negative from 0x80 to 0xFF.